# How can I make these two layered images responsive on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

How can I make these two images responsive with CSS on mobile view? I can't seem to crack this at all, and it's driving me insane.

They are supposed to not be directly on top of each other, but one of them slightly over the other. I'm not exactly sure how to explain it properly, but I really hope that someone can help me fix this.

```css
.content__stacking {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.stacking1 {
  height: 370px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fbf9f6;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.stacking2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 1050px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  /*top: -220px;
  left: -900px;*/
}

.image1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="content__stacking">
  <div class="stacking1">
    <div class="stacking2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <br>Quos natus, corrupti vitae assumenda veritatis consectetur
        <br>debitis corporis ex odit iste voluptates rerum omnis animi ullam itaque.
        <br>Quis quam facilis facere?</p>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <br>Sunt unde reiciendis quod deserunt officia quos consequatur laborum ea amet quo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <img class="image1 img-responsive" src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
    <img class="image2 img-responsive" src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see the images from your code sample. Are you able to share a screenshot of the section containing the problem?

Comment: Please don't use local image paths here. We can't see them. Use a service like [https://placekitten.com](https://placekitten.com), etc.

Comment: I removed the negative position on the relative ".parent" container so at least now your images show and added the cats in.

Comment: @NathanielFlick, probably you solved the problem =))

Comment: Lots of px values don't give me the feeling that things are going to be responsive. But I'm unclear how the text is to be positioned in relation to the img. Could you include a picture of what it should look like a rough hand drawn sketch is fine.

Comment: @Kosh whoops I might have made a too strenuous edit there :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this meets your need
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-fd3nde?file=index.html

```css
.main-container {
        display: flex;
        height: 370px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fbf9f6;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

    .text-container {
        margin: 10px;
    }

    .image-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        width: 350px;
        min-width: 10px;
    }

    .image2 {
        margin: 100px 0 0 -150px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
<div class="text-container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <br>Quos natus, corrupti vitae assumenda veritatis consectetur
        <br>debitis corporis ex odit iste voluptates rerum omnis animi ullam itaque.
        <br>Quis quam facilis facere?</p>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        <br>Sunt unde reiciendis quod deserunt officia quos consequatur laborum ea amet quo.</p>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="image1" src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
    <img class="image2" src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you!!! That was perfect. I wasn't able to upload a screenshot of the images for some reason, but this is great :-)

Comment: Please accept the answer then, if that answered your question @Sarah